# In what regions is the WSO2 Integration Cloud available?

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to find out in which regions the WSO2 Integration Cloud is available.

According to this web page, https://wso2.com/api-management/cloud/, the WSO2 API cloud is available in multiple regions: US East, US West, Brazil (São Paulo), EU (Ireland), EU (Frankfurt), Singapore, and Sydney. But on the corresponding web page for integration cloud, https://wso2.com/integration/cloud/, this information is not available.

So I have the impression the WSO2 Integration Cloud is only available in one region. Is this correct? Does anyone know which region that is? On what cloud provider is it hosted btw, AWS?

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSO2 Integration Cloud is only available in US-EAST region. If you have plans to purchase the subscriptions, please contact cloud@wso2.com so that WSO2 Cloud team will consider providing the runtimes in other regions based on the user demand.

P.N - I represent the WSO2 Cloud team.

Thank you.